# Estimate lines of code in BBC website

Tags: lines-of-code

Does anyone have an estimation for lines of code in BBC News website? (and estimating strategy) http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/

I could not find any estimation methodologies. The closest answer was all about counting lines of code for local projects, but never estimating other websites.

Thanks

Comment: Just the one - Response.Write(news)? Interesting question, but without access to the source code or developers or architecture I doubt it can be answered because it will depend on implementation and a whole host of other things.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you email them and ask them?  They are usually very helpful and open about this kind of thing.  They probably won't let you have access to the source but I don't see why this statistic should be a trade secret.